# How to show loaded reward video in adMobPro?

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-admob, phonegap-admob

I am using https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro in my phonegap application.

**For interstitial and banner I am using**

```
AdMob.showInterstitial();

AdMob.showBanner(getSelectedPosition());
```

is working correctly. Now I am trying to display the Reward video. Firstly I have prepared the Reward video by

```
AdMob.prepareRewardVideoAd({adId: admobid.reward, autoShow: false});
```

Then I am trying to show it

```
AdMob.showRewardVideoAd();
```

But the video is not displaying, The method **showRewardVideoAd()** is my guess w.r.t. `showInterstitial()`, In documentation I have not found any method as `AdMob.showRewardVideoAd()`.

What is the correct method, How should I display it ? please help

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but maybe you should wait for the video to be prepared before calling the `showRewardVideoAd`. Try to call that function from inside the success callback of `prepareRewardVideoAd`.

Also, are you using "Admob." before the function calls? I think it is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Related one:

Being new, I came to this page in the morning and had no luck with -pro module
so, I shifted to -free module
that is, `cordova-plugin-admob-free`

I did several mistakes, but finally solved it, and wrote a github page here, now it works fine:
https://github.com/manoharreddyporeddy/everyday-solutions/blob/master/display-ads-on-android-using-admob.js

Answer (score -1):

All you need to do is implement all required methods like onResume, onPause.

Look at my activity class:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.reward.RewardItem;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.reward.RewardedVideoAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.reward.RewardedVideoAdListener;

public class AdActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RewardedVideoAdListener {

    private RewardedVideoAd mRewardedVideoAd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ad);

        // Use an activity context to get the rewarded video instance.
        mRewardedVideoAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);
        mRewardedVideoAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(this);
        requestNewRewardVideo();
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mRewardedVideoAd.resume(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mRewardedVideoAd.pause(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        mRewardedVideoAd.destroy(this);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void requestNewRewardVideo() {
        //load rewared video
        mRewardedVideoAd.loadAd("ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                new AdRequest.Builder().build());

    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {
        mRewardedVideoAd.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoStarted() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {
        //request for new reward video
        requestNewRewardVideo();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewarded(RewardItem rewardItem) {
        // reward your user here
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int i) {

    }
}
```

app build.gradle

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.4.2'

display ads when Button clicked:

```
if (mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()) {
                mRewardedVideoAd.show();
            }
```